# How to trim text at word boundary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I have the following text:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

I need to get no more than the 12 first characters of the text (just to make the example simple). The first 12 characters are "The quick br". Is there a way in Python to strip the text at the word boundary to get rid of "br"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, there are a few ways to do that. One is using the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> textwrap.wrap('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 12)
['The quick', 'brown fox', 'jumps over', 'the lazy dog']
```

You just take the first element of that and you're done...

Answer (score 4):

Using [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html):

```
In [1]: import textwrap   
In [2]: s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"    
In [3]: textwrap.wrap(s, 12)[0]
Out[3]: 'The quick'
```